# How to get Beacon proximity of Bluecates beacon

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ibeacon, proximity

I have Bluecats Starter Pack and i want to get beacon proximity using didRangeBeacons Methods  but its not call so how to call that methods to get beacon proximity and beacon information

Here is my code

```
- (BCMicroLocationManager *)microLocationManager
    {
        if (!_microLocationManager) {
          //  _microLocationManager = [BCMicroLocationManager sharedManager];

            _microLocationManager = [[BCMicroLocationManager alloc] init];
       _microLocationManager.delegate = self;

        }
        return _microLocationManager;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(microLocationManagerDidEnterSiteNotification:)
                                                     name:BCMicroLocationManagerDidEnterSite
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(microLocationManagerDidExitSiteNotification:)
                                                     name:BCMicroLocationManagerDidExitSite
                                                   object:nil];

    }


    - (void)microLocationManagerDidEnterSiteNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        BCSite *site = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:BCMicroLocationManagerNotificationSiteItem];
    }

    - (void)microLocationManagerDidExitSiteNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        BCSite *site = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:BCMicroLocationManagerNotificationSiteItem];
    }

    - (void)microLocationManager:(BCMicroLocationManager *)microLocationManger didUpdateNearbySites:(NSArray *)sites
    {
        [self refreshNearbySites];
    }

    - (void)microLocationManager:(BCMicroLocationManager *)microLocationManger didEnterSite:(BCSite *)site
    {
        [self determinedState:BCSiteStateInside forSite:site];
    }

    - (void)microLocationManager:(BCMicroLocationManager *)microLocationManger didExitSite:(BCSite *)site
    {
        [self determinedState:BCSiteStateOutside forSite:site];
    }

    - (void)microLocationManager:(BCMicroLocationManager *)microLocationManger didDetermineState:(BCSiteState)state forSite:(BCSite *)site
    {
        [self determinedState:state forSite:site];
    }

    - (void)microLocationManager:(BCMicroLocationManager *)microLocationManger didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inSite:(BCSite *)site
    {
    }

    - (void)microLocationManager:(BCMicroLocationManager *)microLocationManger didUpdateMicroLocations:(NSArray *)microLocations
    {
        BCMicroLocation *microLocation = [microLocations lastObject];
    }
    - (void)requestStateForNearbySites
    {
        NSOrderedSet *nearbySites = self.microLocationManager.nearbySites;

        for (BCSite *site in nearbySites) {
            [self.microLocationManager requestStateForSite:site];
        }
    }
```

Waiting for reply.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Start the ranging of the beacon when it will enter the site. So in method microLocationManagerDidEnterSiteNotification, you have to start ranging like

```
    - (void)microLocationManagerDidEnterSiteNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
    {

        BCSite *site = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:BCMicroLocationManagerNotificationSiteItem];
        [[BCMicroLocationManager sharedManager] startRangingBeaconsInSite:site];
    }
```